# What is the most efficient way of adding a new vertex to edge to graph stored using compressed sparse row format in C#?

Tags: c#, social-networking, gpgpu

I've begun work on a dynamic graph-based analysis tool to help me with my academic research on complex networks.  There are a number of tools out there, but I want to understand the details and the best way is to build my own.  I'm also hoping to develop a Graph Processing Unit using the latest FPGA technology, but will be focusing on GPU-based processing initially to get things going.

At almost the first hurdle I am somewhat stuck.  I have decided to use the compressed sparse row format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29) to store the graphs in as it seems to be very memory efficient.  However, I also need to be able to update the graph by adding new edges and vertices quickly.

One way would be to update the CSR object directly, by extending it by the appropriate number of bytes and then shifting everything to accommodate the new vertex or edge.  Bearing in mind that the graphs could have billions of edges, this seems like a very inefficient way to do it.

Or I could maintain a simple list (Hashtable?) of edges (vertex pairs), and when I want to do some graph-based analysis (like Breadth First Search), I generate the CSR representation from the edge list, before sending it to, say, GPU Global Memory for analysis.  Maybe the generation of the CSR representation itself could be efficiently parallelized into a GPU kernel?  The downside here is that I'm using more than double the memory to store the graph in two formats simultaneously.

Any other ideas?